# Functional continuous mapping theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Consider a sequences of stochastic processes $(f_n)$ on $[0,1]$. If we know that, $\forall u \in [0,1], \, f_n(u)=o_p(1)$ (that is: pointwise convergence to zero in probability), since the integral is a continuous operator, can we conclude by continuous mapping theorem that $\int_0^1f_n(u) du \overset{p}{\to} 0$? My impression is: no, we need a stronger hypothesis on $(f_n)$, such as $\Vert f_n \Vert_\infty \overset{p}{\to}0$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed not sufficient: consider the case $f_n(u)=n\mathbf 1\left\{0\lt u\lt 1/n\right\}$ for $n\geqslant 1$. We have for each $u$ that $f_n(u)=0$  for $n$ large enough but $\int_0^1f_n(u)\mathrm du=1$ for each $n$.

What could help in this context is a use of uniform integrability: if we assume that with probability one, $\lim_{R\to +\infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_0^1 \left|f_n(u) \right| \mathbf 1 \left\{\left|f_n(u) \right| \gt R\right\}\mathrm du=0$. In this case, the result can be used even if the process $f_n$ is not bounded with respect to $u$.

Comment: @ Davide Giraudo: Thank you very much for your answer. I am afraid that the condition you are mentioning might be too strong in many applications (such as in the domain of empirical processes). Then I was considering also another scenario: let's assume that $\Vert f_n \Vert_0^{1-\epsilon} \overset{a.s.}{\to}0$ (here I mean a.s. uniform convergence to zero on the interval $[0, 1-\epsilon]$ for every $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and that a rescaled version of $f_n$, say $\sqrt{n}f_n$ converges in distribution to a stochastic process, say $\mathbb{G}$, which is continuous and vanishes almost surely in 1.

Comment: This could be the case when $\mathbb{G}=\mathbb{B}\cdot h$, where $\mathbb{B}$ is a Brownian bridge and $h$ is a continuous function on $(0,1)$. In that case we could split $\int_0^1 f_n(u)du$ in $\int_0^{1-\epsilon}f_n (u) du$ and $\int_{1- \epsilon}^1 f_n (u) du$. The first term is $o_p(1)$ by a.s uniform convergence. For the second term we can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n}$ and apply continuous mapping theorem first, letting $n\to \infty$, and then use continuity in probability of the limit process in order to claim that, letting $\epsilon \to 0$, $\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 f_n\to_p 0$

Comment: It seems that the assumption of boundedness can be replaced by uniform integrability. Maybe this is not too strong in applications.

Comment: @  Davide Giraudo: Ok, thanks, I will think about it.